# не добавляеться клас к елементам div через classList.add

Tags: javascript

По нажатию кнопки b-7 запускаеться функция f7, которая присваивает блокам out-7 класс .bg-7

ошибка: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
at HTMLButtonElement.f7

```
let button = document.querySelector('.b-7').onclick = function f7() {
let out = document.getElementsByClassName('out-7');
for (let i = 0; i <= out.length; i++) {
    out[i].classList.add('bg-7');
}
```

}

подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема
заранее спасибо!

Comment: Наверное вы хотели написать `out[i].classList.add('bg-7');` ?

Comment: к сожалению не работает

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.f7

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < out.length; i++)` - не 1, а 0. И не `i <= out.length`, а `i < out.length`

Comment: спасибо большое)